# Boot from SD card on Gen8 DL360

Tags: vmware-esxi, hpe

I'm attempting to get VMWare ESXi running from an SD card on an eBay purchased DL360 Gen8. I'm guessing that the firmware is probably out of date (iLO 4 - v2.50).

The only options I have in boot are USB storage device (which I guess the internal SD card might fall into that category).

The question is, could this be firmware related and if so where do I find the correct firmware to update via the iLO web interface. The HPE support site seems to list only firmware which is updated via a host OS.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to see here. I'd created a bootable SD card which didn't actually work. Installed ESXi using a bootable installer on a USB stick on to the internal SD card. Problem Solved.

Comment: Accept your own answer so the question doesn't keep popping up!